# Should we delete answers containing "and see if it works" with reason "should be a comment"?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Sometimes I see an answer of the type "try ... and see if it works", which shows that the author doesn't really know if this is a correct answer or not. But at the same time, I myself can't be sure that it's incorrect.

Example answer which prompted me to ask this question:

> Replace your document.ready with window.load and try...

This answer make it look like the author throwing things at the wall to see if anything sticks. It makes it look like the author himself doesn't know if it works or not, so he's not answering, just guessing.

So should I vote to delete it or not?

Comment: It is generally a sign-post that something is missing from the question. I would address that....

Comment: You can also edit the answer if the answerer is using weasel words to cover a lack of confidence in their answer to the point of being distracting or looking like a non-answer when it really is.

Comment: To me that use of "try"  can also be interpreted as if the answerer is suggesting one out of many possible solutions.

Comment: I have been know to start with a "try this and see what happens" answer, and then improve it, if needed, based on what feedback I get. If it solves the problem, then I'll try to go back and explain _why_ it solved the problem.

Comment: There's another common form that looks even less like an answer at first sight: "have you tried ...?". IMHO, even that qualifies as an answer as long as it proposes something that is helpful. I personally find it annoying, but I don't flag those answers. I agree with @Flexo that it's often just a lack of confidence.

Comment: If the answer is posed like your sample, I'd interpret 'try' as an indicator to perform an action. For example: "Close your browser and try using superfixme to delete Skynet" is more of a case of diction in my opinion.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I'd be tempted to say anything starting with a have-you-tried needs re-wording as a minimum, as it seems to carry a slightly insulting undertone. More an issue of text not conveying subtext brilliantly, of course - and god save us from emoticons.

Comment: If the person asking a question is a beginner, I usually see many things that are wrong with his code. Usually, that means that even if I correct five or six of the mistakes he's made, there are probably other hidden mistakes  from the code that he hasn't posted yet and that I can't even begin to guess about. In those types of cases, that's also when I'll say "try it and see if it works", because I kind of know that his code probably won't work despite all the mistakes I've corrected.

Comment: I'd rather see "hearsay" answers deleted: "X s a good solution, but I haven't tried it myself"

Answer (score 56):

These are attempts to answer the question, and therefore qualify as answers.

If all that a question is getting are "try this and see if it works" answers (where *everyone* is throwing things at the wall and seeing what sticks), chances are the issue lies in the question, and it should be edited or closed where appropriate. Otherwise, I just chalk it up to answerers not being confident enough of their answers, as there are many users who seem to only *ever* post answers saying "try this" regardless of how clear, well-written or even *detailed* the question is.

As always, if you think an answer is uninformative, you are free to comment on it and/or downvote it.

Comment: Personally, I'll say "try X" fairly often even if I'm about 90-95% sure that's the right thing. There's an awful lot of moving parts that can conspire to make even an answer founded in direct recent personal experience that's genuinely analogous to the situation turn out just slightly wrong... enough that suddenly it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't always fully reproduce the problem locally - if it depends on a particular DB, or data file, for example. If that's the case, I'll offer a snippet that I think should do the trick, but usually indicate that it might not work.

Answer (score 25):

More than once I've found myself writing an "answer" that is really a request for more information, for any or all of these reasons:

- I cannot phrase a request for information so that it will make sense to the questioner and still fit under the comment length limit
- The only way to get the necessary information is to instruct the questioner to run a test program; test programs can't be put in the comment box at all (sometimes shell one-liners will fit, but that's rare)
- I have a pretty good idea what the answer is, but there are uncertainties which are easiest resolved by instructing the questioner to try something and see if it works

When I get a reply, I go back and convert the request-for-information into a "canonical" answer, but the questioner does not always reply.  In that case, I feel that someone else with the same problem may benefit from a pseudo-answer that at least gives them something to try, so I leave it as is.

I am generally of the opinion that SO should become less hung up on whether or not questions and answers are "real".  I am also generally of the opinion that comments should be treated as first-class citizens of the site, and made more capable.

Comment: +1 We need **something**, either an enhanced comment or relaxed rules for answers, that accommodates what is logically a comment but cannot fit in the current, very restrictive, comment format.

Comment: "I have a pretty good idea what the answer is, but there are uncertainties which are easiest resolved by instructing the questioner to try something and see if it works"  Easiest yes, but also the least useful.  If you instead write an answer and include the assumptions, even if (due to the uncertainties) it doesn't help the OP, it will help future readers.  "See if this works" fails to communicate how it might fail and when.

Comment: @pnuts: About half of what you mentioned is absurd because it already is documented, just not with the words "assuming that".  For example, the software named in tags is documented by the presence of that tag.  Furthermore, when you provide code, the "assuming you know where to place code" is implicit.  And you can say "This code writes output starting in row 3", that's not an assumption. If you provide code that breaks on European date format, yes that is something you should put in an answer, not as a "try this" for a future reader to stumble upon the problem and have no clue how to address.

Comment: @pnuts: Of course not... that is best handled by a comment "(change A2 to the location containing the signup date)'

Comment: @BenVoigt: Basically, as long as the answer is well on its way to full generalization, it's good enough to post, hopefully with an eye toward future improvements as needed. YAGNI applies to more than just raw code, after all.

Comment: @Nathan: I agree.  And naming assumptions / constraints / design choices is an acceptable alternative to full generalization, because it lays the foundation for a future reader to customize it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Naming *as many of the significant ones as practical*, just to clarify, because noted above, naming literally all of the assumptions is neither at all helpful nor possible.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan So you want to have a forum?

Comment: @GolezTrol Huh? What does that have to do with the format of comments?

Comment: This has inspired me to start http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284440/add-a-information-request-feature-in-addition-to-answers as a feature-request.

Comment: I've learned to use pastebin.com to provide more information in the comments, for example show error logs etc. That is more for questions, though.

Answer (score 5):

For me it's a question of how much substance there is to the "try X...".

If it's something simple that easily fits in a comment (like the example in your question), then I will post it as a comment. If the asker comes back with an "it worked!" I will consider whether to expand it into an answer, or whether the question needs to be closed (a lot of questions that are resolvable via comment turn out to be worthy of closing as dupe or "not reproducible / typographical error" in the end). If someone else beats me to the answer, I don't mind very much.

On the other hand, if the question is decent, and my answer is more complex, involving code snippets and explanation, but I'm less than 100% sure whether it will work, then of course I will post it. If it works, it will hopefully get votes and an accept; if it doesn't, it should prompt the asker to edit their question and I, or someone else, will post a better answer.

From a moderation perspective, I would support giving the benefit of the doubt to things like this. If it's on the road to getting a good question/answer pair, then deletion is too harsh a treatment.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not.

Sometimes while answering the question, the answer does not have a perfect information and has to operate on his assumptions. So he can not tell with high confidence if his solution will work.

For example if the question looks like:

> working with system A when I connected it to B and used a package C
>   and I see the following error. By the way I recently downloaded this
>   github repo.

It is highly unlikely that someone has exactly the same setup and wants to install all these things just to replicate the problem. Or may be the problem is not in set up, but has something to do with the OS OP uses, or he just overwrote some property. So the answerer uses his assumption and prior knowledge to suggest a solution.